# Video upload paperclip ffmepg

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

ffmepg and qtfaststart to process my video uploads. The converting is working fine and the video gets uploaded. My problem is that i can't display it. When I first tried  `<%= video_tag(@post.file.url) %>` I just get a blank area. I've also tried jplayer, got the installation and all working and when i tried to call my video path it doesn't work.

Here is the js code when I tried with jplayer.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
          $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            m4v: "<%= video_tag(@post.file.url) %>"
          });
        },
        swfPath: "/",
        supplied: "m4v",
        solution: "flash, html"
      });
    });
  </script>
```

I don't know how to call the uploaded video and display it, Please really need some help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please always read the documentation. otherwise you will get comments a la RTFM.

when you use `video_tag` it inserts an html5 video element into the page. read about it here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-video_tag

```
<video src="/trailers/hd.avi" width="16" height="16" />
```

this is probably not what you want for your jPlayer. when you inspect the html source, this should be obvious. i did never use jPlayer, but i assume that it would like to be pointed to the streaming source, which i guess is `@post.file.url` in your case.

Comment: Tahnks, yeah i realized that. Now I just have one problem left... Everything works but the problem is that ffmpeg converts the file to mp4 and I can't get it to play in Mozilla Firefox. It works just fine in crome. Can I change the converter somehow? I tried to change format to ogv in my model but no success. Any ideas? :)

Comment: nopse, no credits in movie conversion... maybe this page is helpful for you http://caniuse.com/